# Test multiple projects with dotnet test using pattern

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-test

I am writing a script to build and test projects in a repository. For now I'm using the PowerShell command `Get-ChildItem -Path test -Filter *.csproj -Recurse | ForEach-Object { dotnet test $_.FullName -c $Configuration }` to get all .csproj files in my test folder and run the tests in them. However, I notice when I run, for example, `dotnet test test/ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj` I get this message:

> A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Seeing this, I assumed it was possible to use a pattern to run tests in multiple projects with one command, but I can't find documentation for it or get it to work. When I try `dotnet test test/**/*.csproj` I get:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't seem to be currently supported. For now, the closest alternative is to pass solution file path to the `dotnet test` command. That way, it will run all the tests from all the projects added to the solution.

`dotnet test foo/bar.sln`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName!~YourTestNameOrPartName`

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching is currently not supported in this way. But you can simply call `dotnet test` without a further argument which automatically searches for test projects in the current directory (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test)).

Comment: That's actually not true. It only does if there's a solution file. If you do `dotnet test` inside a folder which just contain other folders it will not find the projects. Just running into this now and it sucks big time. From the docs: If not specified, it searches for a project or a solution in the current directory.

Comment: dotnet test ./somesolution.sln .  I have like 20 test projects in the solution, it is only finding one of the projects. Not sure why is not finding the other 19